# "ToggleKey" like Caps or Num for other keys?

Tags: keyboard, key, toggle, numpad

basically I want to have a program running in background that tracks what keys I press, and I need to enable the "toggle" - state which you know from Caps-Lock to some other keys. 
It should enable me to press e.g. Numpad0 and it will "hold" Numpad0 when I release it, and it should release the key after I've pressed Numpad0 a second time. Basically the behaviour of Num-Lock, Caps-Lock and Scroll-Lock for other keys. Is there a program/code/script w.e. ? I'm running Windows 7 64x bit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use sticky keys? or if you want to program it, which language would you want to use?

Comment: @Rhumborl sticky keys is afaik only CTRL, ALT etc.. I need to "toggle" 8 keys on my Numpad. If I would code it myself I would tend to use Java, since I got some basic knowledge in it. But I don't know how to let java programs run in background and "scan" my keyboard input while I play a game.